# Linq to Sql: Change Conflict SQL Statement

Tags: linq-to-sql, optimistic-concurrency

When I catch a ChangeConflictException is it possible to determine the actual SQL statement that failed from within the code?  ie; rather than inspecting profiler output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I was not asking this question to attempt to perform some kind of optimistic concurrency re-syncing or reporting on fields (which is better performed via `DataContext.ChangeConflicts`).  But anyhow...

You can access the SQL statements executed by the DataContext at anytime provided you log them via DataContext.Log.  A very good tutorial of using this can be found [here](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/07/30/linq-to-sql-log-to-debug-window-file-memory-or-multiple-writers).

An example of writing this to file;

```
db.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("linq-to-sql.log") { AutoFlush = true };
```